# how do i define an isset($_GET['id']) statement in an $_POST update query

Tags: isset

I am carrying 'ID' over from a display table and want to store it in a variable called employee_display_id.  I am aware that if you do not create the below function...

```
if(sset($_GET['id'])){
  $employee_display_id = $_GET['iod'];
}
```

and your proceed to use the '$employee_display_id' variable, you receive an undefined variable error.

How do you incorporate the...

```
if(sset($_GET['id'])){
  $employee_display_id = $_GET['iod'];
}
```

into...

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
  $updatename          = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update_name'])));
  $updateusername      = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update_username'])));

  echo $update_query = "UPDATE `employees` SET `name`='$updatename', `username`='$updateusername' WHERE `employee_id`='4'";/* $employee_display_id */
  $update_result = mysql_query($update_query);
}
  else
{
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

so i can use the variable in the WHERE clause of the UPDATE query??

Answer (score 0):

You are checking isset for `$_GET['id']` and assigning `$_GET['iod']`
itz "iod" yu are assigning. Are you sure this variable assigned a value ???

Answer (score 0):

Nazneen has a point. Double-check your variable names.

Also, do you know the difference between GET and POST? How they work?
Presumably, you want to update the employee data from an update link in a table? So your link would be something like http://example.com/update.php?id=6

Well then, in this example, GET['id'] would return 6, which you can then use with your code and pass it into your SQL query.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $employee_display_id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['update_name'])){
    $updatename = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update_name'])));
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi Ouairz, your presumption is correct...i am updating from a table where i use a link.  I have an isset function for the id to use in conjunction with a SELECT statement and have the variable i am assign the isset to echoed.  This is confirming the passing of the id when i 1st open the update page.  I have then altered my UPDATE statement as you have suggested.  I would add this block of code, but do not know how to do this when adding comments (newbie alert!).  So cannot get my comment to look like your's.  I have an else statement set to 'ID not set' which is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shorthand if to determine if the variable is set within the update command, but you need to set it to something or the query will not operate as you expect.

I would recommend checking if the variable is set prior to the SQL. If it's not set don't perform the query.

```
if(isset($employee_display_id)){
  echo $update_query = "UPDATE `employees` SET `name`='$updatename', `username`='$updateusername' WHERE `employee_id`=" . $employee_display_id;
  $update_result = mysql_query($update_query);
} else {
  echo "ID not set."
}
```

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your reply.  So i have altered my code as described in your answer.  But i also echoed the 1st isset function used in the SELECT query to see whether the variable is being passed from the display table and confirmed this.  After then checking to see if the update button has been pressed using 'isset($_POST['update'])', and setting form variables i use the code as you suggested and the page echoed "ID not set", not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Are you able to post your code in its entirety, or at least the entire update cycle? It sounds as if the setting of $employee_display_id is not occurring properly, but if you are using your code above it should be working [assuming if(sset($_GET... is a typo and should read if(isset($_GET...].

Comment: i am new to stack overflow so am unsure how to add a block of code.  I have tried numerous ways but it will not add the content.  Any other way i can send this code?  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Any other way i can send you this code was what i intended to say.

Comment: Posting large amounts of code in a comment isn't pretty. You can either edit your original question and add it below the original text, or you can use something like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com).